# TinyMCE javascript issue on click of 'paste from word' option after updating to its newer version?

Tags: php, javascript, symfony1, tinymce, text-editor

Previously I was using tinyMCE 3.2 and after upgrading it to 3.5 i am getting a new problem.

It is showing an error that 'page not found' on click of 'paste from word' option.

If I use TinyMCE on localhost, it works fine. Problem arises on putting it into symfony. I just copied whole localhost and pasted into /web folder. All copy-paste-edit are working fine.  only problem is with javascript onclick like features- 'paste from word' and 'inserting image'.

why this issue is with symfony or is there any configuration problem.

Comment: you should check your webserver configuration - i guess the error is to be found there somewhere

Comment: @Thariama:but how come it is working fine with older versions ?

Comment: with older versions of tinymce or simfony?

Comment: Thariama: with older version of tinymce...
I got the solution. In symfony we cannot open a .htm file without proper routing. so, I replaced .htm extesion of image.htm to image.php and also edited for same in js files related to it. But I got another problem. Please look at this [new problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11840599/how-to-get-a-image-path-when-posted-from-tinymce-editor)

Comment: +1 ok then it was a server configuration issue as expected, thx for letting us know your solution